# How do I add MS .NET Framework 4 to Windows Server Update Services?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0

Has anyone had any experience installing MS .Net Framework 4, or 4.5 using Windows Server Update Services?

I can't seem to find the package on the WSUS, and need to deploy this to a number of hosts, so I can install the Windows Management Framework v3 for some Powershell features not available in v2.

Can MS .Net Framework 4, or 4.5 be installed using WSUS, or will this package need to be deployed manually (1 by 1), or by using powershell configuration management (ie, puppet, chef)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET 4.5.2 Framework is [available for install](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsus/archive/2015/01/05/microsoft-net-framework-4-5-2-availability-via-wsus.aspx) via WSUS, you may need to enable the "Feature Packs" update classification to find it. After that approving KB982671 (and KB982670 if you need the .net client profile) for the intended groups should be all that is required.

Comment: To update classification go to: Update Services > Options > Products and Classifications> Classifications